# Workflow/Approval

Tags: community, workflow, approval-process

Email notification to be sent by SF to “X User” for any change in Stage, Total (It’s a custom Field -> Formula -> Currency) and Close Date in the opportunity table for all opportunities that are owned by his team members

1)  Stage – We have diff stages (A,B,C,D,E) – Whenever stage will update email notification mail to be sent to the approver/user manager

2)  Total = (Total 1 + Total 2)  Whenever any changes reflected into the TOTAL, email notification mail to be sent to the approver/user manager

3)  Closed Date -> email notification mail to be sent to the approver/user manager, whenever field is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second query I am unable to get that which object "Team Members" are you referring here.
If I assume that you have only 5 users in that particular profile and the Director/Approver is same for the other 4 users and you want to check the profile for the "Opportunity Owner" to be "SALES USER" , then you can have the workflow to be something like below:

AND((Owner.Profile.Name  = 'System Administrator'), ISCHANGED( Stage ))

Then in the email alert add the "Director" in the 'Recipients' list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 3 new workflow rules for all the three fields on opportunity.
Use "Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited"

Formula would be something like: ISCHANGED(Stage)

Create an Email Alert to send email to users using this workflow.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ruchika, thanks a lot for this and it is working fine.

Comment: I had a small query on the same. Change in Stage, Deal Total and Close Date in the opportunity table for all opportunities that are owned by his "team members" i.e. it will only work for his team member.  I have 5 User all are in the same profile (SALES USER).
Out of 5 users, 1 is the director or approver for all the 4 users.
My Query is that: Once the Stage, Closed date and Total have been changed by any of the 4 users, the DIRECTOR will get the email notification. It will not applicable for Diff profile. Only applicable for same profile